# Get all values for an attribute in a vcard using python vobject

Tags: python, vcf-vcard, vobject

If I import a vcard with vobject like this:

```
with open(some_file_containing_a_vcard,
                  "r" , encoding="utf-8") as fd:
            vcard_content = vobject.readOne(fd.read(),
                                            ignoreUnreadable=True)
```

How fo I get all telephone numbers or emails, if there are more than one provides by the vcard?

I only found:

```
vcard_content.tel.value
vcard_content.email.value
```

...but this only returns the first of each.

As I dived into the code, it seems the entities are created as clases. So a vcard's attribute "TEL" gets created as "tel". What, if I have a cell and a work phone number?

I am totally stuck :-)

Comment: Can you also provide the vCard you're working with?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I solved it in the meantime and I will update this question later. I have solved it by using getChildren() and iterating through all lines of the vcard. This way I fet all information. Example follows...

Comment: great, glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You can actually achieve this by using the `contents` attribute, which is a dictionary. So you would access a list of all TEL properties using something like

```
with open(path_to_vcard) as f:
    text = f.read()

card = vobject.readOne(text)
print card.contents['tel']
```

which will print the list of all TEL properties (even if there is only one or none).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following code snippet:

```
stream = io.open(some_file_containing_a_vcard, "r", encoding="utf-8")
vcf = vobject.readComponents(stream, ignoreUnreadable=True)

for child in vcard.getChildren():
    name = child.name.lower()
    value = child.value
    attribs = child.params.get("TYPE", [])

    filtered_type = [x.lower() for x in attribs if x.lower() in (
                        "work", "home", "cell", "fax"
                    )]
    if len(filtered_type) == 0:
        filtered_type = ["unspec"]

    # Do something with it... i.e. adding to a dict()

stream.close()
```

This works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are attributes named `tel_list` and `email_list` that should provide the other entries you're looking for.

Elements in these lists act just like "tel" and "email", and each also has a `.value`  and `.type_param` that you might want to check to disambiguate.